# V-checkbox input-value on change not working as expected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuex

Template:

```
<template #[`${instanceItemIdKey}`]="{ item }">
 <v-checkbox
    :input-value="item.value"
    @change="$emit('onPermissionChange', item)"
  ></v-checkbox>
</template>
```

The data which gives me `item` is passed through props. The item is dynamic (so I can't use the computed setter). When change is fired it runs vuex action and the mutates the state (I've checked item.value inside vuex-dev-tools and the values are right). BUT the checked state is not changed. How can I change the checked state based on item.value without using v-model?

Comment: have you tried :value

Comment: @GirlCodes, of course, but it's not working with the :value at all

Comment: Try @click.capture and remove every other event on the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

I tried in codepen and this worked:

```
<v-checkbox
    :input-value="item.value"
            @click="changeValue"
  ></v-checkbox>

methods: {
   changeValue: function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation()
      this.callToServer().then(() =>{
          this.item.value = !this.item.value;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        });
    },
}
```

Comment: have you tried to set this.item.value = this.item.value?

Comment: because for example I'm making requests and I don't need to change value if I catch the error

Comment: @Alopwer I didnt understand can you please explain more What do you mean keep it the same? on click you need to toggle it not set it

Comment: I make request on server on click, and if I get the error I need the checkbox to stay the same = not being toggled, that's why I need the value to stay the same in this case

Comment: Then you just do nothing instead of setting it do nothing in that case add if and else

Comment: How can I understand that I should do nothing, if I need to make a request to understand that

Comment: The value is anyway changed, even if I do nothing

Comment: @Alopwer I edited the code for example if you are using axios u do the request first and depending on the response you either change it or do nothing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231472/discussion-between-girl-codes-and-alopwer).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand why it hadn't worked with the v-checkbox, but I've used the v-simple-checkbox with :value and @input